# Apache2 Rewrite in Phalcon PHP Framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phalcon

By default, PhalconPHP offers this type of folder structure:

```
project/
   app/
      controllers/
      models/
      views/
   public/
      css/
      img/
      js/
      index.php
```

And 2 .htaccess Files

```
#/project/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
   RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

#/project/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works with links like: 1) **site.com/controller/method**

But also with public as first segment: 2) **site.com/public/controller/method**

What of Rewrite parameter need to be changed to have access only for first types of links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the first block:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

So something like:

```
#/project/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+public/
   RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]

   RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
   RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nothing changed, same access from both types, is there are any rule to redirect in case if it's valid controller/method, but without public as 1st segment in URL?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't pointing your document root to the public folder which means you can, as you said, access it with or without the public prefix. This will cause problems down the road, but, I will tell you how to fix it.

Make sure your vhost uses the directory "/path/to/project/public" for the document root which will make sure all requests route to index.php inside the public folder. That file will automatically find everything else outside of your document root.

Remove the .htaccess file that is in the root of your project folder, it's superfluous using this method.